# Crop image Processing.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing.js

Processing.js allows to draw an image using:

```
image(x,y,width,height)
```

But adding width & height parameters will only scale the image to that size.
How can I instead crop the image and only draw first `width` pixels to the right and first `height` pixels to the bottom?

Eg, only draw the X'ed part:

```
---------------------------.  
|XXXXXXXXXXXXX             | 
|XXXXXXXXXXXXX             | 
|XXXXXXXXXXXXX             | 
|XXXXXXXXXXXXX             | 
|                          | 
|                          | 
|                          |                            
---------------------------.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can effectively crop an image using the [copy function](http://processing.org/reference/copy_.html)

Here's an example:

```
PImage oImg;
void setup() {
   oImg = loadImage("postgres.jpeg");
   size(oImg.width, oImg.height); 
}

void draw() {
   background(0);
   int iStart = new Float(oImg.width/2).intValue();
   int iWidth = oImg.width-iStart;
   copy(oImg, iStart,0,iWidth,oImg.height,0,0,iWidth,oImg.height);
}
```

This loads an image and then crops it to half its size vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an image sprite:

```
#yourImage
{
    width:46px;
    height:44px;
    background:url(yourimage.gif) 0 0;
}
```

Comment: As I said, I'm using processing.js . The drawing is done on canvas. I'd like to be able to draw (as you said) sprites on canvas, no HTML/CSS involved here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in Processing, but the context's own `drawImage` supports this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage

```
context.drawImage(image, x, y, realWidth, realHeight, startX, startY, drawnWidth, drawnHeight)
```

Comment: See Tobi Lehman answer, seems to be working :D Note that in the Processing file I use no context.